# Update data in current element depending on the next

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of 10 elements. Each element has a field `amount`.

What I want to do is update

```
element[0].Amount = element[1].Amount
```

and so on with

```
element[last].Amount = element[0].Amount
```

I can definitely do this with for loop and couple of statements in it. But is there a way by which I can do this with Linq in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var list = new List<YourTypeHere>();

var first = list.First().Amount;
list = list.Select((x, i) =>
{
    x.Amount = list[(i + 1) % list.Count].Amount;
    return x;
}).ToList();
list.Last().Amount = first;
```

---

**Update** This version does not create a new list:

```
var first = list.First().Amount;
Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
    .Aggregate((c, n) =>
    {
        list[c].Amount = list[n].Amount;
        return n;
    });
list.Last().Amount = first;
```

Comment: 1. You're creating a new list every time  2. The whole thing with LINQ is that lambdas passed to operators shouldn't have side effects, because of _normally_ deferred execution. This is just not something you should do with LINQ.

Comment: This will give a serious impact when the list to be iterated is huge. As @JakubDąbek suggested it is going to create a new list every time. I would recommend to benchmark this kind of query will already available fake data and see the impact when list has fair amount of data in it.

Comment: @AnkurSoni OP explicitly tell us that there only 10 items in a list. However I added a new version of code